# How can I draw projection?

Tags: projection

I am trying to draw this figure.

[image]

I tried

```
Graphics3D[{Polygon[{{-3, -3, -2}, {-3, 3, -2}, {3, 
     3, -2}, {3, -3, -2}}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the projection of this polygon into the coordinate planes?

Comment: You can do like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
{u1, u2} = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
pt1 = {0, 0, 2};
plane1 = InfinitePlane[pt1, {u1, u2}];
c1[t_] := pt1 + {Cos[t], Sin[t]} . {u1, u2};
{v1, v2} = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}};
pt2 = {0, 0, 0};
plane2 = InfinitePlane[pt2, {v1, v2}];
dir = {1, 0, 0} - {0, 0, 1};
sol = Solve[c1[t] + s*dir ∈ plane2, s, Reals][[1]];
c2[t_] := c1[t] + s*dir /. sol[[1]];
{{p1, p2, p3, p4}, {q1, q2, q3, q4}} = 
  Transpose@
   Table[{c1[t], c2[t]}, {t, 
     1 + {0, π/2, 2 π/2, 3 π/2}}];
Show[Graphics3D[{FaceForm[], plane1, plane2}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[c1[t], {t, 0, 2 π}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[c2[t], {t, 0, 2 π}], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[.025], AbsoluteThickness[2], Blue, 
   Line[{{p1, p3}, {p2, p4}}], Line[{{q1, q3}, {q2, q4}}], Orange, 
   Arrow /@ {{p1, q1}, {p2, q2}, {p3, q3}, {p4, q4}}}], 
 PlotRange -> 4, ViewPoint -> {2.3, 0.95, 2.3}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- The idea is at first draw a spatial circle,and set a direction say `({1, 0, 0} - {0, 0, 1})`, then  through every points of the spatial circle we draw lines which parallel to the direction to construct a cylinder. The intersection of such cylinder and another infinite plane is the projection of such spatial circle.

```
e1 = {1, 0, 0};
e2 = {0, 1, 0};
e3 = {0, 0, 1};
Show[Graphics3D[{InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {e1, e2}], 
   InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {e2, e3}]}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, 2} + {Cos[t], Sin[t]} . {e2, e3}, {t, 0, 
   2 π}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, 2} + {Cos[t], Sin[t]} . {e2, e3} + 
   s*({1, 0, 0} - {0, 0, 1}), {t, 0, 2 π}, {s, -10, 10}], 
 PlotRange -> 5]
```

[image]

- Test the projection between two arbitrary planes.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[11111];
{u1, u2} = Orthogonalize@RandomPoint[Sphere[], 2];
pt1 = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 3];
plane1 = InfinitePlane[pt1, {u1, u2}];
c1[t_] := pt1 + {Cos[t], Sin[t]} . {u1, u2};
{v1, v2} = Orthogonalize@RandomPoint[Sphere[], 2];
pt2 = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 3];
plane2 = InfinitePlane[pt2, {v1, v2}];
dir = RandomPoint[Sphere[]];
sol = Solve[c1[t] + s*dir ∈ plane2, s, Reals][[1]];
c2[t_] := c1[t] + s*dir /. sol[[1]];
{{p1, p2, p3, p4}, {q1, q2, q3, q4}} = 
  Transpose@
   Table[{c1[t], c2[t]}, {t, 
     1 + {0, π/2, 2 π/2, 3 π/2}}];
Show[Graphics3D[{FaceForm[], plane1, plane2}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[c1[t], {t, 0, 2 π}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[c2[t], {t, 0, 2 π}], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[.025], AbsoluteThickness[2], Blue, 
   Line[{{p1, p3}, {p2, p4}}], Line[{{q1, q3}, {q2, q4}}], Orange, 
   Arrow /@ {{p1, q1}, {p2, q2}, {p3, q3}, {p4, q4}}}], 
 PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps a litle bit more direct approach than @cvgmt' answer

```
e1 = {1, 0, 0};
e2 = {0, 1, 0};
e3 = {0, 0, 1};
c1[t_] := 2 e3 + {Cos[t], Sin[t]} . {e2, e3};
```

projection

```
p = e3 - e1; (* direction of projection*)
n = e3;      (* normal of projection plane*)   
e = 0 e3 ;   (* point of projection plane*)
proj[x_List] := x -  n . (x - e)/n . p p

Show[{
ParametricPlot3D[ {c1[t] , proj[c1[t]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}  ], 
Graphics3D[{Table[Arrow[{c1[t], proj[c1[t]]}], {t, {0, Pi/2, Pi, 3Pi/2}}]}]
}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Funny how the default colors seem to produce a [Portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_(video_game)).